# Linear equation with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a system of linear equations that I can't solve. I need help. If anyone can help, I'll appreciate. Thanks a lot.

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
Ax+By=C \\ 
Dx+Ey=F \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

where $A,B,D,E$ are square matrices and $x,y,C,F$ are column vectors. They are not a constant, so I got stuck here.

Comment: It is better to use the letters $A,B,C,D$ for the coefficients, and use $E,F$ for the constants behind the $=$ sign. Reason being, that if you solve this system, you will end up with the term $AD-BC$ in the denominator of your solutions of $x$ and $y$. And that turns out to be the Determinant, a very important tool in Linear Algebra as to determine the nature of the system w.r.t. its solution set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say we have $n\times n$ matrices $A,B,D,E$ and $n\times 1$ matrices $x,y,C,F$.  Set up a system 
$$Gz=H,$$
using the block matrices
$$G=\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
D & E
\end{pmatrix},
\qquad z=\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{pmatrix},
\qquad H=\begin{pmatrix}
C \\ E
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Solve this system for $z$, then you will have obtained the components of $x$ and $y$.